# Debugging websites in embedded IE

Tags: javascript, mshtml, firebug-lite

At work, we have a phone system with a dialer component. The dialer component includes an agent script application, which is a fairly simple application that embeds MSHTML. When you login to the dialer, it loads a given URL in the embedded browser control. I don't have access to the source for the application.

I'm currently using firebug-lite for debugging, but it leaves a lot to be desired. Are there alternatives? Please note that I'm currently running IE9, and I've set the meta tag in the HTML to force the embedded browser to use IE8 standards mode (the application doesn't work at all when I use IE9 mode).

Are there alternatives to firebug-lite for these situations? Does anyone know a way to get the IE8/9+ developer tools working in embedded IE?

Comment: I've found IE Dev Tools to be better than FB Lite for IE.  I'm not sure if it will get you exactly what you're after though. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: @RyanO'Neill unfortunately that link is a) not for IE8 and above which have it integrated, and b) an IE addon which doesn't work in embedded applications

Comment: The best way I've found to debug for internal IE stuff is to write stub functions for the things I need, then debug the bulk of the code under IE (or under windows scripting).  It is fugly, bug still better than internal IE.